# text wrapping in a cell of latex table

Tags: tables, formatting, fontsize, makecell

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
\usepackage{booktabs}                               % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell, array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Chiral Superfields in MSSM} % title of Table
    \centering % used for centering table
    \begin{tabular}{ c|ccc|c} 
     %\hline
     \toprule
     \toprule
        & & Spin-0 & Spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ & \thead{ Representation under\\[-0.5ex]\textrm{$SU(3)_c\otimes{SU(2)}_L\otimes{U(1)_Y}$}} \\[10pt]
     \hline
     \multirow{3}{*}{squarks and quarks} &$Q$   & ($\tilde{u}_L, \tilde{d}_L$) & ($u_L, d_L$) & (3, 2, $\mathrm{\frac{1}{6}}$) \\ 
      &$U$   & $\tilde{u}^\dagger_R$ & $u^\dagger_R$ & (\textrm{$\bar{3}$}, 1, -$\mathrm{\frac{2}{3}}$) \\ 
      &$D$   & $\tilde{d}^\dagger_R$ & $d^\dagger_R$ & (\textrm{$\bar{3}$}, 1, \textrm{$\frac{1}{3}$})\\ 
     \hhline{-----}
     \multirow{2}{*}{sleptons and leptons} &L  & ($\tilde{\nu}_L, \tilde{e}_L$) & ($\nu_L, e_L$) &  (1, 2, -$\mathrm{\frac{1}{2}}$)\\ 
      &$E$   & $\tilde{e}^\dagger_R$ & $e^\dagger_R$ &  (1, 1, 1)\\ 
      \hhline{-----}
      \multirow{2}{*}{higgs and higgsinos} &$H_u$   & ($H^+_u, H^0_u$) & ($\tilde{H}^+_u, \tilde{H}^0_u$) &  (1, 2, $\mathrm{\frac{1}{2}}$)\\ 
      &$H_d$   & ($H^+_d, H^0_d$) & ($\tilde{H}^+_d, \tilde{H}^0_d$) &  (1, 2, -$\frac{1}{2}$)\\ 
     \bottomrule
     \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \egroup

\end{document}
```

Everything is fine except that the header in the last column is smaller than the rest of the cells of the table. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please provide a complete compilable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The you need to set the size for the `\thead` command, using the `\theadfont` macro:

```
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
```

should do what you want.